# How to run a java program with multiple class files without making a package?

Tags: java, shell, class

I am very new to Java programming. Since my original java class contains too many methods, I want to move some of them to another class, so I created a new class MergerHTML.

Before having the second class file, I was using command `"javac -cp "./lib/*:lib/*" src/AAA.java"` to compile and using command `"java -classpath "lib/*:lib/*" src/AAA.java data/*"` to run the program. 
I am already confused here. If I do not put `".java"` in the run command, the message:

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class src.AAA
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.AAA"
```

would appear. Why is this happening?

After adding the second class file. I used the command `"javac -cp "./lib/*:lib/*" src/AAA.java src/MergerHTML.java"` to compile the program, and no error found. 
However, when I used command `"java -classpath "lib/*:lib/*" src/AAA.java data/*"`, the following is the resulting error:

```
src/AAA.java:441: error: cannot find symbol
    MergerHTML mHTML = new MergerHTML();
    ^
    symbol:   class MergerHTML
    location: class AAA
```

My main class file look like below:

```
public class AAA {
   ....
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

       MergerHTML mHTML = new MergerHTML();
       mHTML.print();

   }
}
```

and helper class file look like below:

```
public class MergerHTML{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("hiiiiii");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
java -classpath "lib/*:lib/*" src/AAA.java data/*
```

You need to specify the compiled class to execute (not the source it came from), you don't need `lib/*` twice in your classpath, but you do need the current folder (actually, the folder containing your compiled classes, which is the current folder in this case). Like (change `:` to `;` on Windows),

```
java -classpath "lib/*:." AAA data/*
```

**Note**: The more conventional place to put the classes would be a `bin` folder (you can name it whatever you like, but it's more convenient to package when the classes are all collected in a "clean" tree). So, something like

```
mkdir bin
javac -cp "lib/*" -d bin src/AAA.java src/MergerHTML.java
java -classpath "lib/*:bin" AAA data/*
```

**Finally**, if you're on Windows, the last command above should be

```
java -classpath "lib/*;bin" AAA data/*
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick and thorough reply! It really helps me a lot! I just realized that when running the java program, I should be in the directory of `AAA`. Otherwise, I have to add ".java" end the end of the class name.  Moreover, my AAA.class is located at the same directory as MergerHTML.java which is at ./src. I think this directory should be the same as the bin folder you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure I still like the "run single .java files" feature.